# Apply ifelse function to a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I am new using R and probably it is a very basic question. I have some files inside a folder (8 files) and I put all of them together using list.files(). As results I obtain a list of dataframes. My goal now is add the name of each file as a new colum. I am working in the path "C:/test" so each file has the following full name:

```
  > print(filesinfolder)
    [1] "C:/test/alhamilla.csv" "C:/test/amo.csv"       "C:/test/falto.csv"     "C:/test/fbajo.csv"     "C:/test/fmedio.csv"   
    [6] "C:/test/G1.csv"        "C:/test/G2.csv"        "C:/test/G3.csv"
```

I used str_sub() to catch the last characters of the path of each file and then I tried to apply and ifelse function inside a loop to correct the names the columns of all elements in the list. However, despite R expends time processing, it don't show me any error but also doesnt apply my ifelse statement. Any idea about what is happening?

A link with the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Kr0nGPvgQThcmmgKIMVFHrkjHxhnJNqg?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help!!

```
##Read files in the folder:
filesinfolder <- list.files("C:/test",pattern="*.csv",full.names=TRUE) 
files <- lapply(filesinfolder, read.csv, sep = ",")
names(files) <- substr(filesinfolder, 1, 25)

#Add file names in a new colum starting by the end of the file name
    for( i in seq_along(files)){
    files[[i]]$Plot <- paste (str_sub(names(files)[[i]],-13,-1)) }

##Correct the names
for( i in seq_along(files)){
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "alhamilla.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "alhamilla", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "/test/amo.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "amoladeras", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "est/falto.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "falto", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "est/fbajo",      files[[i]]$Plot == "fbajo", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "st/fmedio.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "fmedio", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "/test/G1.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "G1", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "/test/G2.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "G2", files[[i]]$Plot)
  ifelse (files[[i]]$Plot == "/test/G3.csv",  files[[i]]$Plot == "G3", files[[i]]$Plot)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there are prettier ways to do it, such as renaming the column directly in a `map()` function, but here is my suggestion

```
library(tidyverse)
 
list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>%
  map_dfr(~ read_csv(.) %>% 
        mutate(filename = .x %>% 
                 str_remove_all("\\.csv"))) %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = filename, 
              values_from = NDVI) %>% 
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 9 x 8
  alhamilla   amo falto fbajo fmedio    G1    G2    G3
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    0.134  0.171 0.455 0.577  0.307 0.477 0.340 0.339
2    0.0960 0.211 0.457 0.525  0.343 0.405 0.322 0.408
3    0.107  0.220 0.438 0.489  0.370 0.248 0.352 0.428
4    0.149  0.225 0.446 0.505  0.431 0.409 0.345 0.422
5    0.226  0.217 0.465 0.520  0.500 0.497 0.324 0.427
6    0.208  0.200 0.470 0.496  0.523 0.439 0.329 0.455
7    0.155  0.203 0.451 0.440  0.528 0.419 0.305 0.535
8    0.167  0.220 0.436 0.420  0.536 0.413 0.339 0.527
9    0.173  0.231 0.330 0.429  0.488 0.377 0.363 0.419
```